# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION - Java Game

Tags: java, reflection, libgdx

I get the following error when running my game:

[image: As image for copy+paste format issues]

This error occurs when I create an instance of a class called Portal_Sign.  Typically I use the following code:
    game.stage.addActor((Actor) con.newInstance(parameters));
I retrieved the "con" object from Class.class.getConstructor(), which means I'm using reflection to instantiate objects(Because I could be constructing any of many objects, each with reasonably similar constructors).

I know I'm only getting the error when the Portal_Sign is being created.  If I change the values in the Vector2 that represents location to new Vector2(1,1) I don't get a problem.  The same applies for (0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(0,-1),(-1,0),and (-1,-1), or any values that are greater than or equal to -1 and less than or equal to +1.

```
    if(c.getSimpleName().equals(Portal_Sign.class.getSimpleName())){
        game.stage.addActor(new Portal_Sign(game,new Vector2(2,1),0,0,"asdf|ASDF"));
    }else{
        game.stage.addActor((Actor) con.newInstance(parameters));
    }
```

If I create 2 Portal_Signs the error goes away.

Here is some source code:
http://hobogames.atspace.cc/TEMPFORERROR/LevelManager.java 
(Relevant code is in the try/catch at the bottom of the load method)

http://hobogames.atspace.cc/TEMPFORERROR/Portal_Sign.java

http://hobogames.atspace.cc/TEMPFORERROR/packs.level
The file being loaded.  Note, the version uploaded DOES NOT cause error because it creates 2 signs.  HOWEVER, if you remove the last line(Portal_Sign(4,1,0,0,"Baddies|0/32");), you do get the listed error.

http://hobogames.atspace.cc/TEMPFORERROR/Solid.java
The highest parent of Portal_Sign, deals with Libgdx and box2D physics stuff, and the location.

I don't understand why I am getting this issue, any tips would be great, please help.  If you want anything else from me just ask for it.

Comment: You've posted a lot of good info, but not enough.  The error is occurring in the gdx native library, not your code, but you need to track down which bit of your code is triggering it (I suspect it's not in the code you've posted). Use logging, the stack trace or a debugger. You don't get the error if you create 2 x portal_sign, so it's probably not when you're creating one that it occurs.  (PS. your code to use parameter type to figure out argument position looks like a support nightmare, down the track, just saying - I'd do it specific for each class).

Comment: @GregHNZ Well, I did track down the exact line that caused the error... Which was my Portal_Sign constructor.  Without that line there is no error, and if I make 2 there is no error.  If I have a mild position there is no error.  I feel like it has nothing to do with the reflection I used..

Comment: I don't understand how you can make two if there's an error when you make the first?

Comment: @GregHNZ If I make 1 there is an error.  If I put the same line of code twice there is no error.  I don't understand it either, but it's what's happening.  No matter what section of my code I put it in, one game.stage.addActor(new Portal_Sign(game,new Vector2(2,1),0,0,"asdf|ASDF")); gives error, 2 game.stage.addActor(new Portal_Sign(game,new Vector2(2,1),0,0,"asdf|ASDF")); gives no error.  Regardless of distance of the two lines.

Comment: The GDX library is crashing when it looks up the "position" of a Box2D body object.  You should be able to narrow the problem down further (closer to the Box2d primitives).  Pay attention to the "address" your Body objects are getting (see https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body.java#L190)

Comment: Also, read the report error file that was generated in the project root.